# Display JSON String with special character in oracle query using regexp_substr

Tags: sql, json, oracle

I have used following query to display data from JSON string

```
SELECT regexp_replace(
                    regexp_substr('{"id": "1", "contactBy":"Rajesh Kumar"}', 
                    '"contactBy":\s*(".*?")', 1),
                    '"contactBy":\s*"(.*?)"', '\1', 
                    1, 1
                  ) text
  FROM dual;
```

If I have any Special Characters like " (double quotes), the text will not display fully.

```
SELECT regexp_replace(
                    regexp_substr('{"id": "1", "contactBy":"Raje"sh Kumar"}', 
                    '"contactBy":\s*(".*?")', 1),
                    '"contactBy":\s*"(.*?)"', '\1', 
                    1, 1
                  ) text
  FROM dual;
```

ex: Raje"sh Kumar then output display as Raje

but I need output as Raje"sh Kumar.

How can I change my query to display with special characters?

Comment: What version of Oracle are you using? Oracle 12c supports JSON structures and you can solve this without using regular expressions; however, if you are using an earlier version then it will be more difficult.

Answer (score 0):

If you have a quotation mark inside a JSON string then it will be escaped with a backslash:

```
 {"id": "1", "contactBy":"Raje\"sh Kumar"}
```

Use the regular expression `(([^"\]|\\.)*)` to match the values inside the quotes:

```
SELECT REGEXP_SUBSTR(
         '{"id":"1","contactBy":"Quoted \"String\"\\"}',
         '"contactBy":"(([^"\]|\\.)*)"',
         1,
         1,
         NULL,
         1
       ) AS contactBy
FROM   DUAL;
```

**Output**:

```
CONTACTBY
-------------------
Quoted \"String\"\\
```